# Taking the integral $x^3$ using the limit definition

Tags: calculus

So I got as far as setting up the limit as:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left(\frac 6n\right)\left(-3+6\frac in\right)^3$$

However, I'm ending up with $$\lim\left(\left(\frac 6n\right)(27n),n,\infty\right)$$ which is giving me $n$'s in both numerator and denominator, so as a result I am getting a non zero number. What am I doing wrong?

Please help!

Comment: I forgot to add, this is a definite integral from -3 to 3

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please consider learning MathJax typesetting, it's kind of difficult to interpret the question. There is a tutorial here on the site somewhere, probably searchable on the internet also.

Comment: Welcome to the community.  This will help you with the formatting. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \sum_\limits {i = 1}^{n} (\frac 6n)(-3+6\frac in)^3$

Expand out the binomial:

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} \sum_\limits {i = 1}^{n} (\frac 6n)(-27 + 162 \frac {i}{n} - 324 \frac {i^2}{n^2} + 216 \frac {i^3}{n^3})$

If you don't know how do derive these, do you know where to look them up?

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} (\frac 6n)(-27n + 162 \frac {(n)(n+1)}{2n} - 324 \frac {(n)(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2} + 216 \frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{4n^3})$

Simplify
$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} -162 + 486 + \frac {486}{n} - 648 - \frac {3\cdot 324}{n}- \frac {324}{n^2}  + 324 + \frac {648}{n^2} + \frac {324}{n^4}\\
$

As $n$ goes to infinity all of the $\frac {1}{n^k}$ terms go to $0$

$-162 + 486 - 648 + 324 = 0$

Anticlimactic, I know.

But if you look at your function, it is odd, and the region of integration is symmetric about the y axis.  And that means that there is as much area below the x axis on the left side of the $x=0$ as there is above the x axis on the right side.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Not only for your answer but for formatting my question correctly. I realized by following your steps that I left the -27 by itself even after getting rid of sigma, instead of multiplying it by "n". Now all the terms zero out!

Answer (score 1):

We want to evaluate $$\int^{3}_{-3}x^3 \text{ dx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i*)\Delta x$$

We know $\Delta x=\dfrac{b-a}{n}=\dfrac{3-(-3)}{n}=\dfrac{6}{n}$

Also, $x_i^*=a+i\Delta x= -3+\dfrac{6i}{n}$

So, $f(x_i^*)=f(-3+\dfrac{6i}{n})=(-3+\dfrac{6i}{n})^3=\dfrac{216i^3}{n^3}-\dfrac{324i^3}{n^2}+\dfrac{162i}{n}-27$

---

So we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\dfrac{216i^3}{n^3}-\dfrac{324i^2}{n^2}+\dfrac{162i}{n}-27)(\frac{6}{n})$$

Notice that the summation **does not depend on n**, and so we can rewrite the summation as follows:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\dfrac{216}{n^3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3-\dfrac{324}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2+\dfrac{162}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i-\sum_{i=1}^{n}27)(\dfrac{6}{n})$$

*Note*, the following formulas are handy (the first three):

[image]

Therefore, we rewrite our summation as:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(\dfrac{216}{n^3}\cdot\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}-\dfrac{324}{n^2}\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\dfrac{162}{n}\cdot\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-27n)(\dfrac{6}{n})$$

Now we can bring in our $\Delta x$ into the summation, and after that evaluate the limit!

After simplifying, our answer should be:
$$\dfrac{216\cdot 6}{4}-\dfrac{324\cdot 2\cdot 6}{6}+\dfrac{162\cdot 6}{2}-27\cdot 6=0$$

---

*p.s ... when you learn integration properly this will be much much much much easier.*

Comment: A general comment for the OP. This question is not pedagogical at all because, from the beginning, as you integrate an odd function on an interval which is symmetrical with respect to 0, you will end with a zero result

Comment: That's true but then it takes away the ability to learn from a riemann sum defintion

Comment: What I meant is that it would have been as instructive but less tedious to take a Riemann sum associated to the integral of $x^3$ from $0$ to $3$ to find $3^4/4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer K Split, and for all suggestions. I knew how to find the correct answer by taking the integral, but kept having problems doing it using the limit def, which is what I was asked to do. All clear now, thanks!

Comment: Your welcome! get a better username please xD

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle S(2n)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}\frac 3n\left(-3+3\frac in\right)^3=\frac {81}{n^4}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}(i-n)^3=\frac {81}{n^4}\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(i-n)^3+\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^{2n}(i-n)^3\bigg)$

Now in the second sum, we make the change $j=2n-i$

$\displaystyle S(2n)=\frac {81}{n^4}\bigg(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(i-n)^3+\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}(n-j)^3\bigg)=\frac {81}{n^4}\bigg((n-n)^3+(n-0)^3+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}0\bigg)$

We notice that opposite terms $(i-n)^3$ and $(n-j)^3$ appear at the exception of the bounds $i=n$ and $j=0$ that we get out of the sum.

Finally $\displaystyle S(2n)=\frac {81}{n}\to 0$.

It is very similar to prove for $S(2n+1)$ but indexes manipulation and formula writting is less nice, anyway I just wanted to show how to exploit integration of an odd function over a symetric domain. This does not requires explicit calculation of all these $\sum i,\sum i^2,\sum i^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is the limit of the Riemann sum and one can has
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \left(\frac 6n\right)\left(-3+6\frac in\right)^3=6\int_0^1(-3+6x)^3dx=0.$$